# Java to Node JS conversion

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, base64, base32

i have a sniplet of Java code that i need to convert to NodeJS..
The codes purpose

- take a string as an "input"
- Convert the string to a binary array
- Decode the array using Base64 encoding
- Encode the result using Base32

Java Code:

```
import java.util.Base64;

public class func {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String base64SecretKey= new String ("SomeStringGoesHere");
            byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64SecretKey.getBytes());
            System.out.println("Result=" + Base32.encode(decodedBytes));
    }
}
```

At this point all I got is:

```
var string = "SomeStringGoesHere=";

var arr1= [];
var binArr= new Buffer(string, 'utf-8');
for (var i = 0; i < binArr.length; i++) {
    arr1.push(binArr[i]);
}

var b64Dec = new Buffer(arr1, 'base64');

var b32Enc = base32.encode(b64Dec);

console.log(b32Enc);
return;
```